# Какие значения могут быть ключами словаря?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict, типы-данных

Документация гласит, что ключами могут быть только неизменяемые типы данных.
Почему в данном случае не возникает ошибка?

```py
class Test:
    pass

t = Test()
print({t: 1})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221236/how-can-i-make-my-classes-usable-as-dict-keys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробую ответить, т.к. вопрос интересный и сам не знал почему.

Коротко: причина в **наличии** магическом методе [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

Если мы используем словарь как ключ:

```
t = dict()
d = {t: 1}
```

То получаем ошибку:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Но, вообще-то, эту же ошибку получим, если попробуем получить хеш:

```
t = dict()
print(hash(t))
```

У не хешируемых типов, магический метод [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) отсутствует:

```
t = dict()
print(t.__hash__)
# None
```

Вот так выглядит наличие этого метода:

```
print(Test.__hash__)
# <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>

t = Test()
print(t.__hash__)
# <method-wrapper '__hash__' of Test object at ...
```

Мы это легко проверим на нашем классе `Test`:

```
class Test:
    __hash__ = None

t = Test()
d = {t: 1}
```

Знакомая ошибка:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Test'
```

ℹ️ Выходит, что у классов, по-умолчанию, есть метод [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), поэтому их можно использовать в ключах словаря и в других местах (типа множеств), реализованных через хеши

---

Кст, по-умолчанию, хеш высчитывается из `id` объекта деленного на 16.

Тут будет одинаковый результат:

```
class Test:
    pass

t = Test()

print(hash(t))
print(hash(id(t) // 16))
```

Comment: Как-то надо всё-таки переформулировать мне кажется. У словарей атрибут `__hash__` есть, просто он равен `None` и поэтому вызвать его как функцию не получится. Ну то есть да - метода нет, но атрибут есть. Как-то странно они реализовали. Видимо, как атрибут `__hash__` должен быть у всех объектов, что ли, обязательно.

Comment: `hash(id(t) // 16)` - это хэш числа, которое получилось в результате деления, но это не эквивалентно утверждению "хеш высчитывается из id объекта деленного на 16.". При этом утверждение истинное, и `hash(t)` в данном случае действительно равно `id(t) // 16`. То что применение hash к числу возвращает само число - это интересный момент, но это уже просто интересная техническая деталь (ну и кстати получается что для чисел `hash(n) != id(n) // 16`)

Comment: @insolor Да с хэшем вообще много приколов. Например, `hash(-1) == -2`, просто потому, что `-1` у `C++` возвращается в случае ошибки и поэтому `hash` это число никогда не возвращает %)

Comment: Получается, что по такой же логике ключом может быть и `frozenset`. И получается, что утверждение о том, что ключами могут быть только неизменяемые типы не совсем верно, ключами могут быть только `hashable` типы?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, "ключами могут быть только hashable типы?" - да. frozenset - да. Насколько я понимаю, значения в нем априори должны быть хешируемы.