# Как создать не абстрактный метод __hash__ в абстрактном классе Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть абстрактный класс `Type`

```py
class Type(ABC):
    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.text_repr())

    @abstractmethod
    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool: ...

    @abstractmethod
    def text_repr(self) -> str: ...
```

Я хочу сделать метод `__hash__` не абстрактным, но это не работает именно с магическими методами. Если я допустим переименую метод в `hash`, то это будет работать. Но мне нужен именно магический метод, что бы пользоваться структурой данных `set`.

Я использую Python 3.10.6.

Comment: Покажите на конкретном примере проблему. Метод `__hash__` у вас и так не абстрактный в `Type`, т.к. не имеет декоратора `@abstractmethod` (базовый тип `object`, от которого по-умолчанию наследуются все типы, уже имеет метод `__hash__` см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1490448/201445). Другие методы у вас абстрактные, поэтому должен быть какой-то класс, наследующий `Type`, что реализует у себя те абстрактные методы, чтобы была возможность проверить работу `__hash__`. Но у вас этого нет :)

Comment: У меня есть наследники. Как раз если попробовать `Type.__hash__` мне покажет метод. Но у меня есть, например, наследник `Ptr`, если я попробую `print(Ptr.__hash__)`, то я получаю `None`.

Comment: все там выводит https://onlinegdb.com/FdjxwJlrH

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается это специфический случай в Python. То есть без `__hash__ = Type.__hash__` не обойтись.
[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)